# Can I call 2 functions from jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an html button in my asp.net page.

When I click on this button it calls an jquery to replace the contents of a `<div>` with a moving gif progress bar.  Whilst this is showing I also want to call another web method that will load a sprite into that same `<div>` therefore replacing the progress bar with my images(s).

I got the progress bar showing but a bit lost as to how to continue in code getting the next bit.

Here is what i have so far...

*In markup*

```
<div id="divTest"></div>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#<%=btnPlay.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Feed2.aspx/Test",
    data: "{}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (msg)     {                                                            
   $("#divTest").html(msg.d);
   //OK gif is now showing. Now i want to call another web method.
   }
   });
  });
 </script>
```

*in code behind*

```
[WebMethod]
public static string test()
{
string _div = "<div id=\"divBsy\" class=\"background\" style=\"background-position: center center;";
_div = _div + "background-image: url('../Images/ajax-loader.gif'); height: 394px; width: 633px;";
_div = _div + "background-repeat: no-repeat;\" align=\"center\">";
_div = _div + "</div>";
return _div;
}
```

Comment: to load gif image (ajax-loder.gif) you doesn't need a ajax call, you can handle it from jquery itself

Comment: call another $.ajax({]); inside success

Comment: you get your gif from an ajax request??

Comment: I guess what i am after is the syntax to call another ajax function from within an ajax function.Bearing in mind i made a bad career choice just to work with server code :)

Comment: so inside 'success' do I repeat all the info from before.. like this..

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Feed2.aspx/Test2",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg2)     {     }..

Comment: @koala_dev, I am trying to avoid a full post-back. I thought this is the way to go?

Comment: @Janith Chinthana Thanks for replying. The gif needs to be loaded and displaying and then the web method called which will replace that gif. How can I do that sequentially from 1 click? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid the first request to load a gif, you should make your call to load the actual data and use the `beforeSend` option to show the loading gif, this can be simplified if first you make a class in your CSS like this:

```
.loading {
    background: url('../Images/ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
    height: 394px;
    width: 633px;
}
```

Then the ajax call would look like this:

```
$("#<%=btnPlay.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    var $theDiv = $("#divTest");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Feed2.aspx/Test2", //url to get content
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(){
            //Show loading gif
            var loadingDiv = '<div class="loading"></div>';
            $theDiv.html(loadingDiv);
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            //replace gif with content
            $theDiv.html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Love your answer. Very elegant. 1 thing though.  The class property does not change when i inspect the element via Chrome.  I have tested setting the class property at design time and it works. But running it the style is unaffected.  Do you think it is because it is in an ajax call?  Thanks for your time

Comment: @AndrewSimpson So you're saying you don't see the loader gif? try commenting/removing the success function for a bit, then run the ajax and inspect the element, note that we're not adding a class but rather appending a new element with the class to `#divTest`

Comment: Thanks again for replying. I did comment out the method as a test prior to my last comment.  Just to clarify... I already have a <div> called divTest and I am assigning the class to a value of 'loading'> If so, i have done all that and still no joy :(

Comment: Hi, using the asp.net button did not work.  Switching to an HTML DID work.  So, do you think it cannot be done using a asp.net button or is it because i have a script manager on the page as well?  I did enclose that asp.net button with and without update panels and with and without all the different triggers but did not work.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Honestly I don't know what could cause that problem, I'm not very familiar with asp.net. I'm glad you got it working though, just one thing, I noticed you marked another answer as accepted after mine, so mine got revoked, there can only be one accepted answer, but you can upvote multiple answers

Comment: Oops.  Still new to all of this. I will address that now. I only just realised that the 2nd method does not get called. I substituted the method call with an alert box but it did not fire.  But you gave me enough to get going with...

Comment: @AndrewSimpson the success is not getting fired? check your browser's console for any errors and maybe add an error handler function to help debug that

Comment: No errors on the Browser console. Dumb question (and bear in mind i am server-side) how would i add an error function client-side - if that is what you mean?  thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson you add it basically just like the the success one, the error function takes three arguments, you can check [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info, also since you're setting the `dataType` to json you have to make sure to return a proper JSON object from the server, otherwise I believe the success function won't run

Comment: many thanks for the link.  You have given me good info. Thanks for all ur time :)

Answer (score 0):

Call the other function inside that function on the webmethod you're already calling.  If you need to control which one to call you can send that info using the "data: {}" you already have there.

```
data: {
    method: 'whatevermthod'
}
```

Then you get that from the post variable.  Just declare your function in the same document as that other code is in with the _div stuff.

Comment: @Derck HI, thanks for the tip.  I need to return the DIV HTML with a gif and then continue processing a web method.  I am unsure how i can do that from what you kindly suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You could use promises:

```
    $.when($.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Feed2.aspx/Test",
       data: "{}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {                                                            
         $("#divTest").html(msg.d);
         //OK gif is now showing. Now i want to call another web method.
       }
      });
    )).then(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Feed2.aspx/Test2SpriteLoad",
        data: "{id: 1}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg)     {                                                            
           $("#divTest").html(msg.d);
        }
      });
    });
```

And on the server

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Test2SpriteLoad(int id)
{
    var spriteUri = GetSpriteUriById(id);

    string _div = "<div id=\"divBsy\" class=\"background\" style=\"background-position: center center;";
    _div = _div + "background-image: url('" + spriteUri + "'); height: 394px; width: 633px;";
    _div = _div + "background-repeat: no-repeat;\" align=\"center\">";
    _div = _div + "</div>";
    return _div;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this looks very promising (and interesting!).

Comment: I added this:
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#<%=btnPlay.ClientID%>").click(function(){$.when($.ajax({ ... but it did nto work. Am i making a howler somewhere?

Comment: i did not get this to work but i got it solved using @koala_dev's answer.  However, you answer was informative as well. thanks